# avoid reloading JavaScripts files in Partial Views

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

In my project I have a large JavaScript file (bigger than 1 MB) that I use in all pages, I put it in _Layout and every thing work correctly but when I want to update partial view that show a table I loose link between that partial view and JavaScript file and if I want to reload it in partial view users need to waste their time to changes. I use ajax to update partial views.
What can I do to solve that problem?

Java script that I use is:`<script src="~/Content/js/vendor.min.js"></script>`

Ajax that I use to update opartial view is:

```
<script>
    function EditClick(id, pg) {        
        var model = {
            CurrentPage: pg,
            SortColumn: '@Model.SortColumn',
            SortStatus: '@Model.SortStatus',
            id: id,            
    };
    var formDiv = $("#rplaceInsert");
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "Post",
        url: "@Url.Action("EditSurgeryType", "SurgeryType")",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(model)
        ,
        success: function (data) {
            formDiv.html(data);                
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to use that large file and avoid to reload it in partial view

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with reload. Once a file is loaded once in the browser, it will remain cached so telling it to load in multiple places will simply load it from the cache as long as it's all on the same domain.

That said, your issue is because JQuery doesn't automatically apply it's selectors to new elements added to the DOM. It isn't actively watching, so new elements won't get events or be processed unless you do so explicitly.

You can refactor your script so that the parts which apply to your partial view are in their own function. This way, when the partial view is changed, you can call that function to apply your jQuery selectors to them.

If all you're concerned with is hooking up events for in a table or list, you can "defer" those events by putting them on an element higher up in the DOM that doesn't change. Events in Javascript bubble so rather than listening for individual events on items in your table/list, you listen for them once on the list itself. That way, when the table changes, the new elements will still bubble up their events.